# Defining the new frame origin x, y if my image height greater than 412

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, frame

I'm trying to get my button that is inside an image moves to x = 160 and y = 468 if the image have a height greater than 412 but it doesn't worked. I was trying to solve this for auto-layout, but it seems very difficult to the time I have. Can anyone help me or show me an best way to solve this?

part of my .m file:

```
@interface welcomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation welcomeViewController

@synthesize imgWelcome;
@synthesize btnPedir;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self btnLayout];

}

- (void)btnLayout
{
    if (imgWelcome.frame.size.height > 412) {
        CGRect rect = self.btnPedir.frame;
        rect.origin.x = 160;
        rect.origin.y = 468;
        self.btnPedir.frame = rect;
    }
}

@end
```

imgWelcome = image that the button is inside

btnPedir = button

Comment: Where/how is btnPedir defined?  What is its frame before your code executes?  What do you actually see on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- (void)btnLayout {
  if (imgWelcome.frame.size.height > 412) {
      CGRect rect = self.btnPedir.frame;
      rect.origin.x = 160;
      rect.origin.y = 468;
      self.btnPedir.frame = rect;
  }
  }

Here your button y position starts from 468 and you haven't mention what is its height.What my assumption is your button frame is beyond your superview frame.